# Java/MySQL database Issues with Tomcat ELB connection

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

Below is our java code to connnect to the database:

```
    public class DBConnectionFactory {
        private static String dbName = "TEST";

        public static Connection getConnection(Connection conn) {
            Context initContext;
            try {
                initContext = new InitialContext();
                Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
                DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/" + DBConnectionFactory.dbName);
                conn = ds.getConnection();
                return conn;
        }
    public static synchronized void returnConnection(Connection c) {
        try {
            if (c != null)
                c.close();
    }
}
```

Context.xml:

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/Test" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="test" password="test" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" closeMethod="close"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test?autoReconnect=true"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" />
</Context>
```

Java class we are connecting to DB:

```
public class test {
        CallableStatement cStmt = null;
        ResultSet rs1 = null;
        String uuId = getUuid();
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DBConnectionFactory.getConnection(conn);

            cStmt = conn.prepareCall(
                        "{call ap_type_test(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

            cStmt.setInt(1, parameters.getAdID());
            cStmt.setString(2, parameters.getCode());
            cStmt.execute();
            status = cStmt.getString(19);
            result = cStmt.getString(20);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs1 != null) {
                    rs1.close();
                }
            try {
                if (cStmt != null) {
                    cStmt.close();
                }
            try {
                DBConnectionFactory.returnConnection(conn);
                if (!conn.isClosed()) {
                    conn.close();
                }
        }
        return serviceResponse;
    }
```

Issue: With application running on one tomcat server we have no issues. 
       With the load balancing two connections to the database server, we are getting the below errors:
Communications link failure\n\nLast packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
Lock wait timeout errros.

Please help. Can we have two pooling connections from ELB tomcat servers to DB.

Thanks.